# Find record that i have open in new form

Tags: ms-access

I want to find specific record i have opened in form1. But i want to find it in form2. I basically need to grab ID from form1 and search for it in form2. Is that possible?

I thought it's possible by using macro for it but i'm not very experienced in macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this in VBA, depending on exactly what you want to do.

For example, if both forms are open, and you merely wish to synchronize the position of the two forms, than you can use the second form's RecordSetClone:

```
Private Sub cmdBookmark_Click()
    Forms!Form2.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "BillingID=" & Me!BillingID
    If Not Forms!Form2.RecordsetClone.NoMatch Then
        Forms!Form2.Bookmark = Forms!Form2.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
    End If
End Sub
```

Or, if you want to open the second form and only show the record that matches, you can use the `Where` argument of `DoCmd.OpenForm`:

```
Private Sub cmdWhere_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", , , "BillingID=" & Me!BillingID
End Sub
```

If you want to open the second form at the same ID as in the first, but allow navigation through all records, then you can use the `OpenArgs` to pass information between forms. On the first form, have the following VBA:

```
Private Sub cmdOpenArgs_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", , , , , , "BillingID=" & Me!BillingID
End Sub
```

And then on the second form:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst Me.OpenArgs
        If Not Me.RecordsetClone.NoMatch Then
            Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you very much. The last one solved my problem!